# How to Change CiviCRM Contact Mismatched with WordPress User

Tags: contacts, user-account

I have a CiviCRM contact associated with the wrong Wordpress User. I see the link on the contact record but when I got into Edit for that contact the \UserId is not there to edit the link I am a full adminitrator in the CiviCRM.

When the user updates another contact the wrong information name shows up as the source data

Comment: if you have access to your db, look in the uf_match table. i find it is safe to edit values in that table but usual warnings apply

Comment: @petednz-fuzion Thank you I will give it a try. It is od that each user I create randomly matches to an odd contact. Often one with a similar last name. Even when there is an exact match of name and email in CiviCRM it does not match to it.

Comment: check your matching rules. perhaps add a screenshot to the Q above. we have seen people wrongly put eg Length = 2 and then wonder why their matches are all screwed up.